# Laravel - Calculate minimum value from multiple fields in controller

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I want to calculate the minimum value from a collection of form fields.
I have one-to-many relationship, where one shop can have many items ans that is working fine without any errors.

**My form**

```
<form action="{{ route('form_submit') }}" method="post">
 @csrf
 <h3>Item 1</h3>
 <input type="text" name="item[]">
 <input type="text" name="price[]">

//Like this I can add many fields

 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request, $id){
 $shop = Shop::findorfail($id);
 $item = Item::where('shop_id', $shop->id)->get(); //working fine
 $i=0;
 $price = request('price')

  foreach( $items as $item)
  $item->price = request('price')[$i];
  $i++;

 //I tried
  $price_group = collect($item->price)->where('shop_id', $shop->id);
  $min_price = min($price_group);

  $item->save();
}
```

**Route**

```
 Route::post('/{id}', 'Controller@store')->name('form_submit');
```

But it does not calculate the minimum price. When I `dd($min_price)`, its total blank. What am I missing here?

Comment: how you get the `$id` ?

Comment: share your route `route('form_submit')` ?

Comment: $price_group should be a collection, how will the min function find the min in a object?

Comment: how you are passing `$id` is not clear

Comment: @madalinivascu How would I convert? If I changed to ``array($item->price)->where('shop_id', $shop->id);`` its ``Call to a member function where() on array``

Comment: @C2486 Its working fine.

Comment: use `toArray()` to convert the collection to array

Comment: Sorry these line shows bad programming `foreach( $items as $item)
  $item->price = request('price')[$i];
  $i++;`

Comment: @C2486 Where to add? ``$min = ($item->price)->where('shop_id', $shnp->id)->toArray();`` and ``$min = ($item->price)->toArray()->where('shop_id', $shnp->id)->toArray();`` both not working.

Comment: Please add curly brackets to your `foreach` loop.

Comment: Do you want the minimum of `request('price')`?

Comment: So `min(request('price'))`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Yes it solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by [@Jonas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4848587/jonas-staudenmeir)'s solution. And I make this my answer.

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request, $id){
$shop = Shop::findorfail($id);
$item = Item::where('shop_id', $shop->id)->get(); //working fine
$i=0;
$price = request('price')

foreach( $items as $item)
$item->price = request('price')[$i];
$i++;

//This works
$min_price = min(request('price'));

$item->save();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think is just...

```
$items = Item::where('shop_id', $shop->id)->get();

$min = $items->min('price');
```

And take a look on eager loading for relations. It's much better.